# Whitelabel Error Page 404 Api REST Whit Java

Tags: java, spring, rest

I hope your help I have a problem since a week ago I have been with the 404 error it gives me this error:

> "Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sat May 13 12:51:05 CST 2023
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)."

Even though it is only a "hello world" I already tried tutorials and some forums right here and I can not solve it I will leave everything to you the code so that you can help me I would be very grateful with you.

archivo pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Archivo Controller:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */



@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Application.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

AplicationTest:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Aplication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cgbjemct?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = j797EMCt
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Check the URI
check the code

Comment: Hello, modify the package of the classes to be the same. Like com.example.demo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo logre solucionar el problema